# Saving a filtered association with (Fluent)NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following entities

```
User
Job
```

A User has FavoriteJobs. This is a many-to-many association with Job.
Also, this association is filtered so that only active (not archived) jobs are fetched.

The mapping for the FavoriteJobs association looks like this.

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.FavoriteJobs)
.Table("UserJob")
.ParentKeyColumn("UserId")
.ChildKeyColumn("JobId")
.ApplyChildFilter<ExcludeArchivedJobsFilter>("IsArchived = :condition")
.Cascade.None();
```

A job can be archived and un-archived at any time from the application.

When fetching users, the FavoriteJobs collection is populated with the right jobs, only the  active ones.

The problem is that when I want to save a User, all the jobs that were filtered are being treated as though their association has been broken and are deleted from the crossreference table (just like the user marked the filtered jobs as not being favorite anymore).

I am wondering if there are any patterns to mark the filtered entries as being just filtered and not deleted.

Something like disabling the filter from the mapping when there is an update event.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What type of collection?

Comment: I tried with a list and a set

Answer (score 0):

Set collections will completely rewrite the collection when saving so that's why the filtered elements disappear.

I might be that the list collection looses them because of the reason given at [NHibernate - Filtered ManyToMany relationship returns null records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237285/nhibernate-filtered-manytomany-relationship-returns-null-records/14242346#14242346)

Can you try with bag or idbag instead? Or disable the filter during update scenarios.